# Galaxy s5 broken screen use

Tags: broken-screen

My screen is broken but I heard that you can use it by hooking up to a tv (mhl)? Is it true,and could I use an ihome keyboard?

Comment: Problem is, even if you're able to hook, your USB port will be occupied by the adapter, and you can't plug a USB mouse/keyboard in, and you have no way to operate the phone to let it connect to a Bluetooth one either.

Comment: @AndyYan ever heard about USB hubs? Not sure whether MHL works on those, but AFAIK ADB does. And there are several solutions working via ADB to show the screen – some even permit to control the device that way using the mouse, so you won't even need the hub. // **Jeff:** ever considered taking a look at our nice [broken-screen tag-wiki](/tags/broken-screen/info)? You'll be surprised how much of your question (including unasked details) you'll find answered there :)

Comment: Yeah but he specifically mentioned TV, so my first thought is he might not have a PC lying around... MHL adapters are powered, I don't know how well those would work with your average adapters. Plus, in the past I had no luck making hubs working with my devices *at all*.